# Using dynamic values for Kubernetes namespace labels

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I am managing my on-prem Kubernetes cluster namespaces with Terraform and want to include some custom labels/annotations on them. This is to make auditing easier and also we have mutating webhooks that rely on labels/annotations.

I am trying to do something like this (pseudo code)

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "namespaces" {
  for_each = {for k, v in var.namespaces: k => v}
  metadata {
    name     = each.value.name
    annotations = {
    "linkerd.io/inject"              = each.value.linkerd
    {{loop over each.value.custom_annotations}}
    }
    labels = {
      "apps.kubernetes.io/app"       = each.value.app
      "k8s.domain.co/managed-by"   = each.value.managed
      "k8s.domain.co/owner"        = each.value.owner
      {{loop over each.value.custom.labels}}
    }
  }
}
```

I have my var.namespaces variable constructed like

```
  description = "List of namespaces controlled by Terraform"
  type        = list(object({
    name = string
    linkerd = string
    app = string
    owner = string
    managed = string
    custom_annotations = list(object({
      label = string
      value = string
    }))
    custom_labels = list(object({
      label = string
      value = string
    }))
  }))
```

I am trying to end up with

```
namespaces = [
{
  name = foo
  ...
  custom_annotations = {
    label = "myannotation"
    value = "myvalue"
  custom_labels = {
    label = "mylabel"
    value = "myvalue"
}]


resource "kubernetes_namespace" "namespaces" {
  for_each = {for k, v in var.namespaces: k => v}
  metadata {
    name     = each.value.name
    annotations = {
    "linkerd.io/inject"              = each.value.linkerd
    myannotation = myvalue
    }
    labels = {
      "apps.kubernetes.io/app"       = each.value.app
      "k8s.domain.co/managed-by"   = each.value.managed
      "k8s.domain.co/owner"        = each.value.owner
      mylabel = myvalue
    }
  }
}
```

I have a feeling some mix of locals and dynamic blocks would be the solution but I can't seem to pin them together in a way that works

Any advice please?

Comment: You want a nested iterator within a dynamic block for a nested complex type structure. This is kind of a huge effort to provide an answer. Thankfully, there are other answers on SO for how to do this, and also documentation here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/flatten.html#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each and here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this almost working for myself without using locals or dynamic blocks. However I can't include the default labels and annotations

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "namespaces" {
  for_each = { for k, v in var.namespaces: k => v} //loop over the namespaces
  metadata {
    name = each.value.name
    annotations = {
      for annotation in each.value.custom_annotations: annotation.label => annotation.value
    }
    labels = {
      for label in each.value.custom_labels: label.label => label.value
    }
  }
}
```

With this input

```
namespaces = [ 
  {
    name = "metallb-system"
    linkerd = "enabled"
    app = "metallb"
    owner = "KPE"
    managed = "Terraform"
    custom_annotations = []
    custom_labels = [{label="foo.io/bar", value="foobar"}, {label="bar.io/foo", value="barfoo"}]
  },
  { name = "test-ns"
    linkerd = "enabled"
    app = "myapp"
    owner = "Me"
    managed = "Terraform"
    custom_annotations = [{label="foo.io/annotation", value="test"}]
    custom_labels = [{label="app.io/label", value="value"}] 
  }
]
```

It gives me this output

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + namespaces = {
      + 0 = {
          + id       = "metallb-system"
          + metadata = [
              + {
                  + annotations      = {}
                  + generate_name    = ""
                  + generation       = 0
                  + labels           = {
                      + "bar.io/foo" = "barfoo"
                      + "foo.io/bar" = "foobar"
                    }
                  + name             = "metallb-system"
                  + resource_version = "410142"
                  + uid              = "02d6b1e1-707a-49cf-9a2d-3f28c9ce1e5a"
                },
            ]
          + timeouts = null
        }
      + 1 = {
          + id       = (known after apply)
          + metadata = [
              + {
                  + annotations      = {
                      + "foo.io/annotation" = "test"
                    }
                  + generate_name    = null
                  + generation       = (known after apply)
                  + labels           = {
                      + "app.io/label" = "value"
                    }
                  + name             = "test-ns"
                  + resource_version = (known after apply)
                  + uid              = (known after apply)
                },
            ]
          + timeouts = null
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to add default labels and annotations using [setunion](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/setunion)

```
locals {
  default_annotations = [{label = "foo", value = "bar"}]
  default_labels = [{label = "terraform", value = true}]
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "namespaces" {
  for_each = { for k, v in var.namespaces: k => v} //loop over the namespaces
  metadata {
    name = each.value.name
    annotations = {
      for annotation in setunion(each.value.custom_annotations, local.default_annotations) : annotation.label => annotation.value
    }
    labels = {
      for label in setunion(each.value.custom_labels, local.default_labels) : label.label => label.value
    }
  }
}
```

I know this doesn't exactly solve your use case, as you are wanting to read the value from your list of namesapces, however I do think it is one step closer!